# Rotate UIImageView inside UIScrollView in Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, autolayout, transform

I'm working in a basic photo editor which is supposed to zoom, rotate and flip a photo. I'm using an image view (aspect fill) inside a scroll view which allows me to zoom easily. But when I try to rotate or flip the result is not what I would expect. The image view keeps the original frame and seems like rotating the image. The scroll view zoom scale changes. Any suggestions on how to do this?

It also would be great to have suggestions about setting the image view anchor point to match the scroll view anchor point before transforming cause I don't want to display a different portion of the image after transforming, just the same portion of the image, but rotated.

View stack before transform:
[image]

View stack after applying rotation:
[image]

My code so far:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        setZoomScale()
        scrollView.zoomScale = scrollView.minimumZoomScale
}

@IBAction func rotateAnticlockwise(_ sender: UIButton) {
        rotationAngle -= 0.5
        transformImage()
}

func transformImage(){
        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        transform = transform.rotated(by: .pi * rotationAngle)
        imageView.transform = transform
}

func setZoomScale(){
        let imageSize = imageView.image!.size
        let smallestDimension = min(imageSize.width, imageSize.height)
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scrollView.bounds.width / smallestDimension
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = smallestDimension / scrollView.bounds.width
}
```

Comment: "the result is not what I would expect" So what _would_ you expect? It is unclear what the goal is here.

Comment: I would expect the imageView frame to be transformed, but it seems to rotate only the image instead.

Comment: The way to create a rotated version of an image is to rotate the _image_. Not an image view. The actual image.

Comment: I've tried rotating the image and creating a new image view with the rotated image then removing the old image view and adding the new one. But the scroll view will not update its content size at all. Even if I set the content size to the new image view content size at running time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for, e.g. :

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0.5)
```